# Math in ladder logic

Tags: plc, ladder-logic

I'm just starting up learning ladder logic, more specific in GP Pro EX. I'm trying to get the gist of how to do math proberly in LL.
Right now i have values that i want to multiply be eachother, but one of them is a decimal number, and the other one is an integer. The numbers are:
0,000244141 * 6202, is there a good solution do multiply these numbers?

In advance, thanks.

I tried using the multiply blocks already in the program, but i have no idea how to get a decimal number multiplied in the program. Please help

Comment: You say you tried already with multiply blocks. What was the result that you got? What is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: Make sure you are doing floating point math - some instructions may be doing integer math and truncating your real number down to integer 0.

Comment: Hi guys, appparently i misunderstood the output blocks. Had to change everything to 'real' to make it work. Thanks!